# How to save and show Mapbox directions?

Tags: django, leaflet, gis, mapbox

I am using Mapbox and Leaflet.
I have a create view, where I create walking directions.
But I also need detail view, where I can show created directions.

Now I save only originMarker and destinationMarker coordinates into database;

This way I try to show routing:

```
<script>
        var start = JSON.parse($('#start_field').val());
        var finish = JSON.parse($('#finish_field').val());
        L.mapbox.accessToken = 'qwerty';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', {
        zoomControl: false
    }).setView([42.8580536, 74.6224754], 12);

        L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(start.lat, start.lng),
                L.latLng(finish.lat, finish.lng)
            ]
        }).addTo(map);

        var start_marker = L.marker([start.lat, start.lng], {
            draggable: false
        }).addTo(map);

        var finish_marker = L.marker([finish.lat, finish.lng], {
            draggable: false
        }).addTo(map);
    </script>
```

But browser gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'control' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the full code it's kind of hard to answer but my first guess is that you didn't load the routing plugin's assets or not in the proper order (first the Leaflet script then the routing plugin, the other way around doesn't work):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet-routing-machine.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>
```